# Como eliminar carácter estranho aparecendo no cabeçalho da página

Tags: php, css

Em minha página faço um include para um cabeçalho que fica no topo da página, mas estranhamente está ficando um `sujeira` que dá um espaço bem no início, não sei muito bem o que é e nem o que fazer, estarei postando uma imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha página com o include é essa:

```html
<?php 

 if(!isset($_SESSION)) {    
   session_start();    
 }

 // Require da classe de conexão
 require_once "_classes/conexao_pdo.class.php";
 require_once "_classes/crud.dsc.class.php";

 // Instancia Conexão PDO
 $conexao = Conexao::getInstance();
 $crud = Crud::getInstance($conexao);

 $dados = isset($_SESSION["dados"]) ? $_SESSION["dados"] : unserialize($_COOKIE["dados"]);
 $email = $dados["email"];

 if ($email != "") {
  // BUSCANDO PRODUTOS
  $RelUsuario = "SELECT *
      FROM cadclientes
      WHERE cadclientes.email = ? AND acesso_usuario = 1";
  $stm = $conexao->prepare($RelUsuario);
  $stm->bindValue(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stm->execute();    
  $RelUsuario = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
  $stm->closeCursor();

  $NomeUsuario = "";

  foreach($RelUsuario as $NomeUser) {
   $NomeUsuario = $NomeUser->nome;
  }

 }

?>
<div class="top-bar">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
   <ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="icon-user"><a href="minha-conta-login.php"><img src="assets/img/icon-1.png" alt=""/> <span>Faça Login</span></a></li>
    <li class="icon-form"><a href="cadastro-cliente.php"><img src="assets/img/icon-2.png" alt=""/> <span>Ou cadastre-se, entre aqui</span></a></li>                      
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
   <ul class="list-inline">
    <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="sobre.php">Sobre Nós</a></li>                    
    <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="contato.php">Contato</a></li>
    <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
    <?php if ($_SESSION["dados"] != "") { ?>
    <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="index.php">Olá <?php echo $NomeUsuario; ?></a></li>  
    <li class="hidden-xs"><a href="logoutCliente.php">Sair</a></li> 
    <?php } ?>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Página em desenvolvimento:

[Página para visualização](https://rendamaislingerie.com.br/n-renda/contato.php)

Comment: Cara, tive um problema igual e consegui resolver, por isso marquei como duplicata blz?

Comment: Nessa página em particular tirando o ` line-height: 1.72; do <body> ` e colocando de volta apenas nos "vomponentes" `.footer e .top-bar` vc resolve o problema. Mas reparei que nas outras páginas não apresenta o problema, mesmo o body tb tenho esse line-height: 1.72; ... Eu até tinha postado como resposta, mas preferi te questionar antes, pra vc testar ai e ver

Comment: Olha a imagem do teste https://imgur.com/zbbzpEE as vezes pode te ajudar se não conseguir resolver de outra forma...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que as respostas anteriores resolvam o problema, mas em último caso você pode resolver usando CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    margin: -25px;
}
```

Comment: Olá @Jota, valeu pela dica, levando em consideração os comentários anteriores consegui resolver de duas formas, uma como você indicou e outra como o hugocsl, esse SO é realmente muito bom.

Comment: Sempre que precisar.